# Find X so that the graph resulting from decoding the Prufer sequence 1,1,7,X,3,3,7,6,7 has all vertices with an odd degree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Find x so that the graph resulting from decoding the Prufer sequence 1,1,7,X,3,3,7,6,7 has all vertices with an odd degree. The graph has 10 vertices (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

I didn't know how to find X, so instead I tried a brute force approach. I chose a value from 1 to 10, replaced it with X in the sequence, and decoded the sequence. However, all the time, in the resulting graph at least one vertex had an even degree.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

When X = 1 this is the graph I get. At some point while decoding I run out of numbers, so as not to add 11 I use 1 again (because the problem says |V|=10)

Comment: Can you show the tree you got when $X=1$? I think I know what mistake you made, but need to see some of your work to confirm.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I updated the post with the tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see there is something wrong, since the graph you posted has a cycle.

The problem here is that you are mixing up Prüfer sequences for *unrooted trees* with Prüfer sequences for *rooted trees*. The former is a bijection between lists of length $n-2$ with unrooted trees, and the latter is a bijection between  lists of length $n-1$ with rooted trees. Your sequence must fall in the latter case, since it has length $9$.

In the rooted case, the bijection is slightly different; for a list $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1}$, you form a tree by, for each $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$, finding the the current smallest vertex without a parent and not appearing in $a_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_{n-1}$, and making its parent $a_i$. For example, when $X=1$, the correct result of the bijection is the following rooted tree, where $7$ is the root.

```
        7
      / | \ 
     3  5  6
    / \    |
   1   9   10
 / | \
2  4  8
```

I *believe* this is equivalent to ignoring the last sequence element, using the unrooted Prüfer bijection to make an unrooted tree from the first $n-2$ symbols, and then having the last symbol be the root.

**Hint**

To solve your problem, you only need these basic facts about the rooted Prüfer correspondence:

- The number of times each index $i$ appears in the sequence corresponds to the number of children that $i$ has in the corresponding rooted tree.
- The degree of a vertex is $1+(\text{# children})$, unless that child is the root, in which case the degree is the number of children.
- The root of the tree corresponding to a sequence is the last entry of that sequence (so $7$ is the root for your sequence, no matter what $X$ is).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I've never learnt of these facts before. So in this case X would be 6, right? Because the degree of 7 is 3, the degree of 1 is 2 + 1, the degree of 3 is 2 + 1, and the degree of 6 is 1+1 (without X being 6). So X must be 6

Comment: @aneys That's correct :)